# Combinations with cost and budget

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following list of items I may purchase.

```
Apple or Orange- $1
Pear or Plum - $2
Grapefruit - $3
Watermelon - $5
```

Such that I have **no more than two of any item**, *except for Apples,* of which I may have up to 10.

My budget is **$10**. How do I figure:

- The total number of combinations of items?
- What those combinations are?

My math school days are far behind me- would this be permutations or combinations?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Also, because I'm realizing this looks a lot like a homework problem, I should mention I haven't done homework in 15 years!

Comment: Alas, I don't see any better method than listing out all of the combinations.  Start with 2 watermelons.  Then 1 watermelon 1 grapefruit, 1 pear, etc. until you have exhausted the possibilities.  It doesn't seem like there are that many to enumerate.

Comment: Do you have to spend exactly 10\$, or not more than 10\$? Does 1 watermelon is a valid combination?

Comment: Generating functions might help, but this method is almost the same as listing all the combinations.